# CSP testing locally - how can I allow for everything aside from unsafe evals

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have an error being thrown in an upper environment:

`EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive:`

I can't recreate this locally so I'm trying to essentially allow for all script sources, etc, and only block what are considered "unsafe evals".

I've tried a number of things with my `<meta>` tag in the index.html file, but everything I've tried so far ends up blocking other dependencies I need. This is just for testing purposes, I need to figure out if that error is breaking something in the upper environment (as everything is working locally). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. **WARNING: For testing purposes only, do not use in production**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data: blob: 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

This has allowed me to only get that unsafe eval error.